# Liferay 7 blade.strutsportletaction installed but not working after Login

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I am developing a Blade service Strutsportletaction from liferay blade sample (blade.strutsportletaction) as I need to navigate to a different page after loging in. I am using blade hook and blade.strutsportletaction to modify the log in page and also navigating to custom page after successful login.

Both are deployed and are active but when I log in, it does not go to custom page instead it goes to default page.

Comment: ...and the code that does not work can be found where? Check https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - this helps more than stating that your problem is urgent to you, because it's not urgent to anyone else.

Comment: I guess Chika refers to this example https://github.com/liferay/liferay-blade-samples/tree/master/liferay-gradle/blade.strutsportletaction